# Add Javascript src path to Symfony Webpack Encore

Tags: php, symfony, webpack

I have the following javascript links and other custom js files:

```
<script src="/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

How do I add them to my `app.js` webpack file?

I tried:

```
import './js/popper.min.js';
import './js/moment.min.js';
import './js/custom/js';
```

Then when i run `npm run dev` , i get the following error:

```
Module build failed: Module not found:
"./assets/js/moment.min.js" contains a reference to the file "./locale".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.
```

How do i solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use webpack Encore you have to :

1. Install the dependecy thans to a package manager like npm or yarn with for examaple `npm install popper --save` or `yarn add popper`
2. Add the dependency in your app.js like this : `import 'popper.js';` and that's it ! It the same way for Moment or any other JS library.

**NB : if you want to include a custom JS file you have to put it in the asset folder (where you want) and include it as you did :  `import './js/custom/js';`.**